# Uniqueness of the Jordan decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

I have seen it said that a matrix $M$ (over $\mathbb{C}$, say) has a unique decomposition $M = D + N$ where $D$ is diagonal and $N$ is nilpotent. I'm having trouble seeing this, since the Jordan form of a matrix is only unique up to ordering of the blocks. Wouldn't a different ordering give you different matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sami Ben Romdhane's answer shows that the decomposition must be unique. However, I think your question still applies, whether how this can be, if the Jordan decomposition is not unique, namely only up to reordering of the blocks.

The Jordan decomposition of $M$ looks like
$$M=PJP^{-1}=P(J_D+J_N)P^{-1}$$
where $J_D$ is the diagonal of $J$ and $J_N$ contains the offdiagonal entries. Now, the matrices in your decomposition are clearly $D=PJ_DP^{-1}$ and $N=PJ_NP^{-1}$. If you look at another Jordan decomposition which leads to a reordering of the blocks you will have
$$M=P'J'P'^{-1}=P'(J'_D+J'_N)P'^{-1}$$
The matrices $J'_D$ and $J'_N$ will of course be different from $J_D$ and $J_N$, but the matrix $P'$ "contains" this block reordering, such that $D=PJ_DP^{-1}=P'J'_DP'^{-1}=D'$ and $N=PJ_NP^{-1}=P'J'_NP'^{-1}=N'$.

If it's not yet evident, you can also write $J'=RJR^T$, where $R$ is a permutation matrix that leads to this block reordering (note $RR^T=I$). Then $P'=PR^T$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Jordan–Chevalley decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Chevalley_decomposition): If $M$ is a matrix with  coefficients in a field $\mathbb{F}$  such that it's caracteristic polynomial splits over  $\mathbb{F}$ then there's a unique $(D,N)$ where $D$ is diagonalizable matrix and $n$ is nilpotent and $M=D+N$ and $DN=ND$.

For the unicity of this decomposition, suppose there's $(D,N)$ and $(D',N')$ such that
$$M=D+N=D'+N',$$
then $D-D'=N'-N=0$ since the zero matrix is the unique matrix diagonalizable and nilpotent.

Comment: Can you please prove why 0 is the only matrix which is both diagonalizable and nilpotent?

Comment: @user1685224 Zero is the only eigenvalue of a nilpotent matrix so if $A$ is a nilpotent diagonalizable matrix then it's similar to the zero matrix so $A=0$.

Comment: Let me add one thing: $D-D'$ is diagonalizable because $D$ and $D'$ commute.

Comment: @user63181: You can not sure $N-N^{'}$ is nilpotent ! So you said $A=D-D^{'}=N-N^{'}$ is a diagonalizable matrix but not a  nilpotent matrix.-1

Comment: Unfortunately user202406 is correct, making this answer invalid: the sum of two nilpotent matrices is not necessarily nilpotent. Counterexample here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701819/properties-of-nilpotent-matrices

Comment: Moreover, WWK's comment raises the point that $D-D'$ isn't necessarily diagonalizable. It must be shown that $D-D'$ commute, according to that comment, and further, it must be shown that this commutativity would imply $D-D'$ is diagonalizable, which isn't clear to me.