# Specific decomposition of quadratic 2x2 matrix

Tags: matrices, self-learning, matrix-decomposition

Consider the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$. Prove that there is only one decomposition A = B + C with $B,C \in \mathbb{R}^{2x2}$ that fulfill the following criteria and determine those matrices B and C:

(i) $B$ is diagonalizable,

(ii) C is nilpotent,

(iii) BC = CB,

Comment: [relevant](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/336642/81360)

Comment: The adjective "quadratic" in your title should be removed : I don't know what a quadratic matrix is...